# Expressing $A\sin x + B\cos x$ as a sine -- $A,B \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Suppose we have the expression $P=A\sin x + B\cos x$ , where $x$ is real and $A,B$ are complex numbers. Can we then write $P$ in the form $C \sin y$  , where obviously $C=C(A,B)$ and $y=y(A,B,x)$, with $y$ preferably being real ?

In the case where $A,B$ are real positive numbers, it's fairly easy to do. In fact it holds that $P=R\sin(x-a)$ where $R=\sqrt{A^2 +B^2}$ and $a=\arctan\frac{B}{A}$. We can find that by demanding $$A\sin x+B\cos x = R\sin(x+a) = R(\sin x \cos a + \cos x \sin a) $$ 
From which we can see that we need $R\cos a= A $ $(1)$ and $R\sin a=B$ $(2)$.

Thus, by doing the following two steps:
$$(2)/(1) \implies \tan a= \frac{B}{A} $$
$$ (1)^2 + (2)^2 \implies R^2 = A^2 + B^2$$

However when they are complex, dividing (1) and (2) gives us again $\tan a= \frac{B}{A} $ but now $a$ and thus $\tan a$ is real, but $ \frac{B}{A}$ is generally complex. Is there another (any?) way of doing this?

Comment: @MCCCS I will edit it, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Letting $C$ be a function of $x$ is a nonsense, as it suffices to take $C(A,B,x)=A\sin x+B\cos x$, with $y(A,B,x)=\pi/2$.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I didn't think much when writing that. C will be a constant, which depends on A,B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to work with $y$ real.

Indeed, when $x$ varies $A\sin x+B\cos x$ describes an ellipse in the complex plane, while $C\sin(y)$ is a line segment.

Comment: Does it not matter that $y = y(A,B,x)$?  e.g. if $y = x + AB$, then $C \sin y = C \sin(x + AB) = C \sin x \cos AB + \cos x \sin AB$ isn't a line segment, right?

Comment: @tilper $y=x+ AB$ isn't real though. He said it doesn't work when y is real, not generally.

Comment: @tilper: if you drop the restriction that $y$ be real, the question is of little interest as the formula (actually a conversion from Cartesian to polar) just generalizes to complex.

Comment: @Dimitris, why is $x + AB$ not real?  I see that $A$ and $B$ are complex but that doesn't necessarily prevent $AB$ from being real.  Are $A$ and $B$ restricted to be complex so that $AB$ is non-real?

Comment: @tilper generally $A, B$ are complex, thus $AB$ is (generally) complex,may be real or not. I'm interested in the general case. In the special (real number) one I showed what holds and I want to know if it generalizes, which it doesn't.