# Trigonometric relation, implication of the requirement $\theta_a = \theta_b$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

This question is related to [a previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220721/132192). Consider the following two quantities:

$$A = a_1 \sin (n \alpha) + a_2 \cos (n \alpha)\\
B = b_1 \sin (n \alpha) + b_2 \cos (n \alpha)$$

with

$$n \in \mathbb{N}\\
\alpha \in [0; 2\pi)\\
a_{1,2}, b_{1,2} \in \mathbb{R}$$

It is possible to rewrite them as

$$A = A' \sin (n \alpha + \theta_a)\\
B = B' \cos (n \alpha + \theta_b)$$

If I require $\theta_a = \theta_b$, does this imply any condition upon $a_{1,2}, b_{1,2}$? Note that there is no requirement on $A'$ and $B'$: they can differ.

---

I have no clue about how to proceed. Taking the case $a_1, a_2 > 0$, $b_1, b_2 > 0$,

$$\theta_a = -\arctan \left( \frac{a_1}{a_2} \right)$$
$$\theta_b = \arctan \left( \frac{b_2}{b_1} \right)$$

This seems to be true only when $a_1 = b_2 = 0$, or $a_1 = b_2$ **and** $a_2 = -b_1$. But this would violate the initial hypothesis $a_1, a_2 > 0$, $b_1, b_2 > 0$, so maybe only $a_1 = b_2 = 0$ is acceptable.

How to consider all the remaining cases?

Comment: The arctangent is injective on its domain.

Comment: It seems to me that you need $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 = 0$. If you need the coefficients to be nonnegative, then at least one of $a_1$ and $b_1$ has to be 0 and at least one of $a_2$ and $b_2$ has to be 0.

Comment: @SohomPaul How do you obtain the relation $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 = 0$? The coefficients $a,b$ may also be negative; there is no limitation on their sign.

Answer (score 1):

$A = A' \sin (n \alpha + \theta) = 
     A' \sin(n \alpha)\cos(\theta) + A'\cos(n \alpha)\sin(\theta) =
     a_1 \sin(n \alpha) + a_2 \cos(n \alpha)$

$B = B' \cos (n \alpha + \theta) =
     B' \sin(n \alpha)\cos(\theta) + B'\cos(n \alpha)\sin(\theta) =
     b_1 \sin(n \alpha) + b_2 \cos(n \alpha)$

You must have

$$A'\cos(\theta)= a_1$$
$$A'\sin(\theta)= a_2$$
$$B'\cos(\theta)= b_1$$
$$B'\sin(\theta)= b_2$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{a_1}{A'} = \dfrac{b_1}{B'}$$
$$\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{a_2}{A'} = \dfrac{b_2}{B'}$$
$$A' = \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}$$
$$B' = \sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2}$$